# How can I show custom 400 error page in playframework 1.2.x?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

My issue is I want to give a bad request response for a given request but also render a pretty nice page for the user to look at. How can I create such a template in playframework 1.2.x?

Thanks,
Val

Answer (score 1):

You just have to create a new package named "errors" in your "views" package.

Then you can create customized error pages named "404.html", or "500.html", etc. inside your "errors" package.

Comment: I don't think it's the best way, but you could handle the error 400 and then use the renderTemplate to display the error 400 page.